# How to make encryption in transit for env vars in AWS Lambda repeatable with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to deploy an AWS Lambda function. The function has some environment variables that should be encrypted such as API keys/tokens.

In the AWS console, I can enable helpers for encryption in transit, and then encrypt any sensitive environment variables using a specified KMS key e.g.

Check the following checkbox when editing lambda environment variables:

[image]

By checking the checkbox above, an 'Encrypt' button becomes visible next to each of my environment variables.

[image]

If I choose to encrypt a specific enviornment variable, a modal dialog appears where I get to choose a KMS key to use for the encryption. The dialog also shows some code about how to decrypt the secret in the lambda function.

After encrypting the environment variable, I can see that the value has now been encrypted e.g.

[image]

---

I'm using Terraform to deploy my AWS resources, and I can copy the cipher text (from the AWS console) to my tf variable (in tfvars) instead of having it in clear text in my Terraform repo e.g. in the code below `var.elastic_api_key` will be the cipher text.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  # Other resource attributes here
  kms_key_arn = aws_lambda_function.this.arn

  environment {
    variables = {
      ELASTIC_API_KEY = var.elastic_api_key
    }
  }
}
```

My question is; how can I automate this and make it repeatable? Currently, if I destroy my terraform deployment (or deploy to a different env), I'll need to go in and re-encrypt my sensitive environment variables and copy the cipher text into my tfvars file. The KMS key that I use for the encryption/decryption is a symmetric key that will be regenerated each time e.g. config for the `aws_kms_key` is as follows:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "this" {
  description              = "lambda environment variable decryption"
  key_usage                = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
  customer_master_key_spec = "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"

  tags = merge(local.common_tags, { Name = "${local.naming_prefix}-key" })
}
```

Note: I understand there's other ways to secure sensitive data in my tf repo e.g. gitcrypt my tfvars file, Terraform Cloud, etc., but just wondering if there's a way to make encryption in transit for env vars in AWS Lambda repeatable.

FYI., AWS has the following information for encription in transit:

> For storing sensitive information, you can encrypt environment
> variable values prior to sending them to Lambda by using the console's
> encryption helpers. This adds an additional layer of encryption that
> obscures secret values in the Lambda console and API output, even for
> users who have permission to use the key. In your code, you retrieve
> the encrypted value from the environment and decrypt it by using the
> AWS KMS API.

Comment: Well, you could use [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html) or [Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_lambda.html) instead. That way you wouldn't need to worry about which value you are passing to the Lambda function, as you can provide the encryption key to the service.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @MarkB replaced images with code. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The AWS console is taking the text you entered, and making a call to the KMS API to encrypt that text. It is then setting the encrypted text as the environment variable value. You should be able to follow that same process in Terraform using the [aws_kms_ciphertext](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kms_ciphertext) resource.

```
resource "aws_kms_ciphertext" "elastic_ip_key" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.this.key_id

  plaintext = var.elastic_ip_key
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  # Other resource attributes here

  environment {
    variables = {
      ELASTIC_API_KEY = aws_kms_ciphertext.elastic_ip_key.ciphertext_blob
    }
  }
}
```